# Ruby extract subarray from integer

Tags: ruby

I need to extract part of an array based on an integer and if there are no enough values, fill this array with specifics values if the array size doesn't feet with this integer.

As example :

I have an array like that:

```
[[1,2], [2,1], [3,3]]
```

If my integer is 2 I need this :

```
[[1,2], [2,1]]
```

If my integer is 4 I need this :

```
[[1,2], [2,1], [3,3], [nil, nil]]
```

Comment: for what reason you need this behavior?

Comment: It's for generating an xlsx file with multiple limited tables

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do the same using `Fixnum#times` methos:

```
a = [[1,2], [2,1], [3,3]]

def extract_sub_array array, size
   size.times.map { |i| array.fetch(i, [nil, nil]) }
end

extract_sub_array a, 2
# => [[1, 2], [2, 1]]
extract_sub_array a, 4
# => [[1, 2], [2, 1], [3, 3], [nil, nil]]
```

Comment: You can use fetch to return a default value: `array.fetch(i, [nil, nil])`

Answer (score 4):

```
def convert(a,n)
  Array.new(n) { |i| a[i] || [nil,nil] }
end

a = [[1,2], [2,1], [3,3]]

convert(a,2) #=> [[1, 2], [2, 1]] 
convert(a,3) #=> [[1, 2], [2, 1], [3, 3]] 
convert(a,4) #=> [[1, 2], [2, 1], [3, 3], [nil, nil]] 
convert(a,5) #=> [[1, 2], [2, 1], [3, 3], [nil, nil], [nil, nil]]
```

Comment: I just noticed that @Doguita posted (then deleted) the same solution a few seconds after I posted. We must have had a mind-meld. That probably explains why I was thinking of a beautiful woman named 'Gertrude', who I've never met.

Comment: Nice. BTW, `a.fetch(i, [nil, nil])` works here, too.

Comment: @Stefan, yes, I noticed you had suggested that to Arup as well. I must use `fetch` more often, on both arrays and hashes.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming, the `desired_length` is specified and an array is named `arr`:

```
arr = [[1,2], [2,1], [3,3]]

# Will shrink an array or fill it with nils
# @param arr [Array] an array
# @param desired_length [Integer] the target length
def yo arr, desired_length
  arr[0...desired_length] + [[nil,nil]]*[0,desired_length-arr.length].max
end

yo arr, 2
#⇒ [[1,2], [2,1]]

yo arr, 4
#⇒ [[1,2], [2,1], [3,3], [nil, nil]]
```